# Calling read syscall from assembly (x86/64) yields segmentation fault (compiler construction)

Tags: assembly, compiler-construction, x86, system-calls, static-linking

I am building a compiler for a C-like language, and i'm trying to link a basic "void readString(int, char*)" function implemented in assembly, with assembly generated by my compiler.

The compiled c-like file is

```
void main () {
    char t[20];     
    readString(7,t); // Read 7 bytes and place them in t buffer
}
```

After the compilation, The resulting file is: out.s file (notice that the calling convention is: passing arguments through stack. also Integers have  2 bytes size in this language):

```
.$0:
.globl main
main:
pushq %rbp
movq %rsp,%rbp
subq $20,%rsp

.$1:
movw $7,%ax  # Push first argument in the stack
pushw %ax

.$2:
leaq -20(%rbp),%rax # Push address of the second arg in the stack
pushq %rax

.$3:
subq $8,%rsp   # this is not important, needed for the convention being followed
pushq 16(%rbp) # pushing "access link",
call _readString 
addq $26,%rsp # caller clears the "leftovers" 

.$4:
.$main_0_11:
movq %rbp,%rsp
popq %rbp
ret
```

Code in reads.asm for the library function:

```
.intel_syntax noprefix
            .global _readString

_readString     push    rbp
            mov     rbp, rsp
            push    rdi
            push    rsi

            mov     rdi, [rbp+32]           # First argument 
            mov     rsi, [rbp+34]           # Second Argument

            mov     rdx, rdi

doRead:
            mov     byte ptr [rsi], 0x00
            xor     rax, rax
            mov     rdi, rax
            syscall                         # read syscall, reads up to $rdx bytes
            or      rax, rax                # nothing read
            jz      finish                  #
            add     rsi, rax                #
            cmp     byte ptr [rsi-1], 0x0a  # check if last character read was '\n'
            jne     addZero                 #
            sub     rsi, 1                  # if so, replace with '\0'
addZero:
            mov     byte ptr [rsi], 0x00
finish:
            pop     rsi
            pop     rdi
            pop     rbp
            ret
```

The linking/running follows

```
$ gcc -c out.s
$ gcc -c reads.s 
$ gcc out.o reads.o 
$ ./a.out
[2] Segmentation fault  ./a.out
```

A Picture that depicts the calling convention

[image: calling convention]

Comment: You are almost certainly dealing with a stack alignment issue.  Look up the calling convention and make sure that your stack is properly aligned before the call.

Comment: You were absolutely right! Thank you :-) I will post the fix

Comment: IDK if you realize, but you're inventing your own non-standard 64-bit calling convention here.  x86-64 System V and Windows pass function args in registers.  (And when they run out of registers, narrow args still take 8B stack slots; they never use PUSHW).  See the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) for ABI links, and also look at gcc/clang output to see how they do it.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed answer. I do realize that, but this is an esoteric compiler, so it doesn't need to conform to any standard convention. I didn't know about x86 tag wiki though. Thanks for posting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, as @David Hoelzer suggested i checked again the way "readString" grabs the arguments from the stack and they were reversed in order!

So the first lines of reads.asm will become

```
_readString:
            push    rbp
            mov     rbp, rsp
            push    rdi
            push    rsi

            movzx   edi, word ptr [rbp+40] # Get first argument, check comments for more info
            mov     rsi, [rbp+32]  # Second Argument


            mov     rdx, rdi
```

Comment: Rather than  `mov     di,  [rbp+40]` `and     rdi, 0xffff` you could just do `movzx  rdi, word ptr [rbp+40]` which would move the 16-bit word from [rbp+40] and zero extend it across the 64 bit register _RDI_ Even better would be to do `movzx   edi, word ptr [rbp+40]` which would encode to fewer bytes but do the same.

Comment: I had made a small addition to my first comment that does the same in a shorter encoding by using _EDI_ instead of _RDI_. The reason zero extending just to the 32-bit register _EDI_ works is because in 64-bit mode, when the destination register is 32-bit the CPU automatically zero extends it across the corresponding 64-bit register (_RDI_ in this case). Using _RDI_ in this case encodes as a 5 byte instruction with a prefix byte, where as _EDI_ will encode to 4 bytes.

Comment: Nice! Do you happen to know why this is the case? Is it on purpose or just because no-one cares about zero extending half the register and to avoid further complication of the hardware?

Comment: If you are referring to the CPU automatically zero extending a 32-bit destination register to the 64-bit register (in 64-bit mode) it has more to do with performance from the processors perspective as it can reduce false dependencies and partial register stalls.